# Create and write a file in one atomic operation on OS level

Tags: java, file, io, atomic

So I need to create a file then write one line to it and this must be atomic. So that no other process may tinker with the file whilst it is under initialization.

I have one idea, to lock on something different then while the lock is held, do the operations then release the lock to let the other party in. But this is quite tedious, also may be erroneus because creating the lock and acquiring it might be not atomic (I guess). No other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to write temporary file and then *rename* it to your file. I am not sure this operation is implemented in java as atomic for all operating system but at least on Unix you have a chance because I think it uses the same call as `mv` that is atomic.

It will not be truly atomic on windows, I guess. It will be "almost atomic" that is enough for most applications.

Comment: Thanks we've already considered it, but its javadoc is quite discouraging... Anyway seems to be no other alternatives except for the java7 `Files.move`. Too bad we're on java6...

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that will be safe guarded from other processes, I suggest that you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking and utilize JNI to get to the OS level.

Comment: But if I create the file then lock on it, that is also 2 operations being not atomic (at least with `FileLock`). The other process might have a chance to slip in between the 2 steps, am I right?

Comment: Would help to know what OS your dealing with so more specific answers can be given.

Comment: win7. And in the future it's still gonna be win whatever. Anyway it is not a concern so great that we are willing to make this part native. We most likely will stick with the create-then-rename scenario.